# sql where score >= s.score

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a question about sql. I have a question looks like this.

```
 +----+-------+
 | Id | Score |
 +----+-------+
 | 1  | 3.50  |
 | 2  | 3.65  |
 | 3  | 4.00  |
 | 4  | 3.85  |
 | 5  | 4.00  |
 | 6  | 3.65  |
 +----+-------+
```

The table is called 'Scores' and after ranking the score here, it will look like this,

```
 +-------+------+
 | Score | Rank |
 +-------+------+
 | 4.00  | 1    |
 | 4.00  | 1    |
 | 3.85  | 2    |
 | 3.65  | 3    |
 | 3.65  | 3    |
 | 3.50  | 4    |
 +-------+------+
```

Here is a sample answer but I am confused about the part after WHERE.

```
select 
    s.Score, 
    (select count(distinct Score) from Scores where Score >= s.Score) 
 Rank
 from Scores s
 order by s.Score Desc;
```

This Score >= s.Score is something like Score column compare with itself. I totally feel confused about this part. How does it work? Thank you!

E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a *dependent subquery* (and can be quite inefficient). A *dependent subquery* - basically means it cannot be turned into a join because it "depends" on a specific value - runs for *every* result row in the output for the *specific* "dependent" values. In this case each result-row *already* has a "specific" value of `s.Score`.

The 'Score' in the dependent subquery refers *to the original table* and not the outer query.

It may be more clear with an additional alias:

```
select 
  s.Score, 
  (select count(distinct other_scores.Score)
   from Scores other_scores
   where other_scores.Score >= s.Score) Rank -- value of s.Score is known
                                             -- and placed directly into dependent subquery
from Scores s
order by s.Score Desc;
```

"Modern" SQL dialects (including [MySQL 8.0+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)) provide "RANK" and "DENSE_RANK" *Window Functions* to answer these sorts of queries. Window Functions, where applicable, are often much faster than dependent queries because the Query Planner can optimize at a higher level: these functions also have a tendency to tame otherwise gnarly SQL.

The *MySQL 8+* SQL Syntax that ought to do the trick:

```
select 
  s.Score, 
  DENSE_RANK() over w AS Rank
from Scores s
window w as (order by Score desc)
```

There are also [various work-abouts to emulate ROW_NUMBER / Window Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) for older versions of MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not it :}

Comment: What is an efficient way to do this? Any examples or key words that I can search in google? i don't even know what to search. lol

Comment: @Eleanor See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql - note that *MySQL 8.0* adds as `RANK` function. The answers there also show alternative methods for earlier MySQL versions. (This shows I've not used MySQL in years..!)

Comment: @Eleanor If using MySQL 8+, I would recommend using the new [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) support and "DENSE_RANK". I've also updated the answer to include the link, and to reflect that MySQL has finally fixed this coverage gap..

Comment: @Eleanor I've "copied" the syntax from the link into the question and modified it slightly for the table, although I have not verified it - I'm not a MySQL user. YMMV. :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to understand this is to just run the query for each row of your sample data.  Starting with the first row, we see that the score is `4.00`.  The correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
(select count(distinct Score) from Scores where Score >= s.Score)
```

will return a count of 1, because there is only one record whose distinct score is greater than or equal to `4.00`.  This is also the case for the second record in your data, which has a score of `4.00` as well.  For the score `3.85`, the subquery would find a distinct count of 2, because there are two scores which are greater than or equal to `3.85`, namely `3.85` and `4.00`.  You can apply this logic across the whole table to convince yourself of how the query works.

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    | <-- 1 score >= 4.00   
| 4.00  | 1    | <-- 1 score >= 4.00
| 3.85  | 2    | <-- 2 scores >= 3.85
| 3.65  | 3    | <-- 3 scores >= 3.65
| 3.65  | 3    | <-- 3 scores >= 3.65
| 3.50  | 4    | <-- 4 scores >= 3.50
+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is dependent subquery. Every subquery will need to be re-evaluate on each row from outter query. If you familiar with Python, you can think of it like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
ScoreTuple = namedtuple('ScoreTuple', ['Id', 'Score'])
Scores = [ScoreTuple(1, 3.50), 
          ScoreTuple(2, 3.65), 
          ScoreTuple(3, 4.00), 
          ScoreTuple(4, 3.85),
          ScoreTuple(5, 4.00),
          ScoreTuple(6, 3.65)]
Rank = []
for s in Scores: # each row from outter query
    rank = len(set([innerScore.Score                  # SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Score)
                    for innerScore in Scores          # FROM Scores 
                    if innerScore.Score >= s.Score])) # WHERE Score >= s.Score
    Rank.append(rank)
```